# SafeConfigParser overriding files

Tags: python, configuration-files

I am making a chat application, and need a conf file for the server and another for the client. However, whenever I run the client its conf properties get transferred to the configuration file of the server even though I am using SafeConfigParser. Is there any way to fix this?
Thanks.

when server starts:

```
config = configparser.SafeConfigParser()
config.read('chatserver.conf')
config['PORT']['port'] = str(self.port)
with open("chatserver.conf","w") as configfile:
   config.write(configfile)
```

when a client joins:

```
clientconf = configparser.SafeConfigParser()
clientconf.read('chatclient.conf')
clientconf['SERVER']['last_server_used'] = str(self.host)
clientconf['SERVER']['port_used'] = str(self.port)
with open("chatserver.conf","w") as confFile:
    clientconf.write(confFile)
```

chatclient.conf:

```
[SERVER]
last_server_used = '127.0.0.1'
port_used = '50000'
default_debug_mode = False
log = True
default_log_file = chat.log
```

chatserver.conf:

```
[PORT]
port = '1000'
```

When I run the server, a client joins the chat, and close it, then run the server again, the chatserver.conf file becomes the same as chatclient.conf

Comment: Without seeing your project layout and code, it is impossible to tell. You'll need to provide more information.

Comment: Added more info sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line:

```
with open("chatserver.conf","w") as confFile:
    clientconf.write(confFile)
```

You save `clientconf` as `chatserver.conf`. I think you mean to save as `chatclient.conf` instead.